# Classloader load incorrect log4j.xml

Tags: java, maven, log4j

I have java maven project with below structure

AA.ear

|_ lib

    |_ parent_config.jar

       |_ **log4j.xml**

    |_ child_config.jar

       |_ **log4j.xml** [`this is expeccted to load`]

|_ BB.war

---

I am using **log4j 1.2**. For parent_config.jar is dependency project which inherit by child_config.jar. Both of them have log4j.xml. Classloader read log4j.xml from child_config.jar all the time but since upgraded to Spring 4, it does not work as expected. It turns out load log4j.xml from parent_config.xml.

I tried remove log4j.xml from parent_config.jar by 7zip and at the end it works as expected. Moreover, the limitation here is I should build parent_config.jar as usual (without remove log4j.xml) because it used by other project also. And excluded approaches of using WEB-INF/lib and -Dlog4j.configuration

May I know is there any suggestion on this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Within some runtime environments, it may be possible to control the order of classpath entries. But I wouldn't recommend that.

You should provide a custom log4j configuration file with a different name then `log4j.xml` and/or not located in the classpath root and configure it via the system property `log4j.configuration`.

Comment: log4j.configutation is not so suitable. i would rather configure in application instead of vm. but even though use this approach, it required classpath [com.aaa.bbb.ccc] or external location [file:////path/to/xml]. how should i point my log4j.xml by log4j.configuration follow my current project structure?

Comment: I deliberately didn't express my own opinion in the answer above. From my point of view, it doesn't make much sense to provide a logging configuration along with a JAR file (e.g. an API). You may provide a default configuration for your application. But even then I would plead not to use the default name and location and document an overriding mechanism. In short: you are not able to choose one of those two files. The first one in the classpath is taken.

Comment: Although it has not proofed, I believe it was because the parent_config.jar used in other standalone project so the configuration located in the jar file. Agree that configuration setting should located in application level because it is WEB-BASED project. Fortunately, I managed to "force" the classloader read correct log4j.xml by changed the file name and referencing to log4j.configuration. it could be a temp solution. Still working on it, Thanks Frito!!